# Failure delivering result ResultInfo keep throwing

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have an activity that opens camera but if a was in the camera and a click on back button it give me this error every time.

```
Process: com.deraah.mohamed.deraahpro, PID: 13346
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.deraah.mohamed.deraahpro/com.deraah.mohamed.deraahpro.ParticipantsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
    at com.deraah.mohamed.deraahpro.ParticipantsActivity.onActivityResult(Unknown Source:37)
```

Failure delivering result ResultInfo keep throwing evry time.

This is my activity `ParticipantsActivity`:

```
class ParticipantsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888
    private var imageView: ImageView? = null
    private var MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_participants)
        this.imageView = this.findViewById<View>(R.id.imageView1) as ImageView
        val photoButton = this.findViewById(R.id.button1) as Button

        photoButton.setOnClickListener { view ->
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                        MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
            } else {
                val cameraIntent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                val cameraIntent = Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }


    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        if(data != null){
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                try {

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

And after that the app is stopped working.

Comment: try by changing:
`override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {`

To:

`override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {`

Notice the question mark at the end of `data: Intent?`

Comment: Can you please check by changing Intent to Intent? on this line override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent)

Comment: Yes its work perfectly

Answer (score 5):

Your code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
```

There are parameter `data` should never be null, because it has type `Intent` (not nullable).

Your error talks about it:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: ... parameter **data**

Simply change `data: Intent` to `data: Intent?` and `data` will be specified as nullable parameter.

Read more about null safety in Kotlin: [documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: +1 already, Here is the link related to Documentation about Null safety in Kotlin http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: should we call super method? `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)`?